# public Google Drive link to file in Java - How to generate it?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, storage, drive

How to generate Google Drive share links to a file with Java. I could not find any solution in other posts. All I saw was solutions in other programming languages but not in Java. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my adapted class on Github:
https://github.com/otakuu/sz2pdf/blob/master/src/main/java/sz2pdf/UploadGoogleDrive.java

I guess, you'll find there what you need.

```
public String getUploadFileLink() {
        return "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + uploadedFile.getId() + "/view";
    }
```

Comment: And it will be available for everybody to download that file from that link?

Comment: @otaku you understand that the file id changes right? its not a static id.  This link will also only work for those people who have access to the file.

Comment: Yes it changes for every file. And it is "public". Since it is hard to bruteforce this ID id call id semi-secure. When you have very confidential data, i wouldn't push it at all to google-drive.